# <Head> in _document.js or _app.js

Tags: next.js

Should I use `<Head>` from `next/head` and use it inside `_app.js` or should I use `<Head>` from `next/document` and use it in `_document.js`?

I'm kind of confused about when should I choose what. From what I understand `_document.js` is only rendered on the server-side and `_app.js` is rendered on both client-side and server-side.

**Things I've learnt so far:**

- [Viewport meta tags should not be used in _document.js's](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-document-viewport-meta)
- [`<title>` should not be used in _document.js's](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-document-title)

Does that mean I can just put everything `<Head>` related inside `_app.js` and be done with it? Or does it give any advantage to put all the other tags(except title and viewport) in `_document.js`?

Answer (score 7):

You can put anything related to `Favicon`, preloading `Fonts`, `GTM` ..etc in `_document.js` and `Viewport` meta related can be added into `_app.js`. For other other meta tags like `robots`, `og`, `twitter`, ... etc can be added in `<Head>` of each page in your app.

[image]

Comment: Yup. I was kind of wondering what benefit will it give if I can put all these things in _app.js too.

Comment: Is there any benefit of putting it into the _document.js file? Or any cons putting it into the _app.js file?